# Stretch a ViewGroup to its contents in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a customized `ViewGroup` with some items inside. I would like to height of the `ViewGroup` to be stretched as long as possible to fit the contents. How can I achieve this?

**NOTE**: I have already tried with `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` without success.

Comment: you can also use Weight property...

Comment: did you override onMeasure?

Comment: well, just do it, see existing implementations in, for ex, LinearLayout